# MVC nice urls and special chars in regex

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

How to edit this this regex `Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"[^a-z0-9]", "-");` to not delete special characters like `ę,ą,ó,ł`, etc?

Here is my method. I use it to generate nice URL's, without these chars `.,#$%@:;` in URL.

```
    public static string ToSeoUrl(this string url)
    {
        // make the url lowercase
        string encodedUrl = (url ?? "").ToLower();

        // replace & with and
        encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"\&+", "and");

        // remove characters
        encodedUrl = encodedUrl.Replace("'", "");

        // remove invalid characters
        encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"[^a-z0-9]", "-");

        // remove duplicates
        encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"-+", "-");

        // trim leading & trailing characters
        encodedUrl = encodedUrl.Trim('-');

        return encodedUrl;
    }
```

Regards

Comment: You're specifically removing anything that's not `a-z0-9` - if you have specific characters you want to keep, add them to that list.  If you don't have a finite list, you'll need to rethink how you're doing the replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the special characters to the character class:

```
@"[^a-z0-9ęąół]"
```

The regex essentially matches on anything that isn't a-z, 0-9 and whatever other characters you put between the `[]` - that is the meaning of the `^` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't answer your question directly, the following method for stripping accents, diacritics etc might be handy.

```
    public static String RemoveAccentsAndDiacritics(this String s)
    {
        return string.Join(string.Empty,
                           s
                               .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
                               .Where(c => 
                                  CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != 
                                      UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark));
    }
```